# Language switcher flydown block

Tags: 7, theming, i18n-l10n

I want to theme the language switcher on my Drupal 7 site:

In the header of my site the language switcher shows the actual/selected language and looks like this:

- "EN"
- "▼"

If you click on the down array, the menue block slides down, shows all languages and looks like this (vertical layout, fly-down, without list-style dot):

- "EN"
- "FR"
- "DE"
- "SP"
- "CN"
- "▲"

If you click on the up array, the menue block closes und looke like above.

If you click on one of the language shortcuts the language of the site changes.

How can I realize this vertical arranged language switcher with slide effekt using jQuery?

How can I change the language labels and use shortcuts (EN, FR, SP, ..) instead?
Thank you very much.

Comment: Is there anybody who can help?